# Cannot connect to a server on Cent OS Machine

Tags: linux, centos, lighttpd

I have installed CentOS as a virtual machine (using Virtual Box), on my Windows OS. I am running a lighttpd server on my CentOS machine. I am trying to access the server, from my browser, which is running on Windows, using the IP address and port number. But, I am getting the following error: `Firefox can't establish a connection to the server at 10.209.145.152:8080`.
Also, when I am running the server on Ubuntu(as a virtual machine using VMware Player), I am able to connect from the Window's browser successfully. Can anyone please suggest me, what I might have been missing on CentOS Machine. Thanks.

Comment: If my answer has answered your question, please set it as the correct one, so I can get some points :-) Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest that it is something that has to do with the VM setup. Compare the configuration of your Ubuntu VM and the CentOSVM. In order to connect from Windows to the VM, I think that you need to setup  a bridge network connection rather than NAT. But I am not sure, so I would suggest you try all the different options.

Hope that helps!